# Comparing umbraco.library:CurrentDate() with a datepicker field

Tags: xslt, datepicker, umbraco

I am having trouble with the following problem. I want to compare two **Date Picker with time** fields with **umbraco.library:CurrentDate()** so that i can make an XSLT which does three different things depending on what time it is compared to what time i entered in the two **Date Picker with Time**.

Currently, i have this:

```
<xsl:variable name="currenttime" select="umbraco.library:CurrentDate()" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$currenttime &lt; dateEvent">
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">Event is not yet live</a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$currenttime &gt; dateEvent and $currenttime &lt; dateEventpassed">
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}/live.aspx">Event is live</a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}/different.aspx">Event has passed</a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
```

But it somehow does not seem to work. Might this have anything to do with the way either date is formatted? I'm not even close to being an expert in Umbraco so any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referencing `dateEvent` and `dateEventpassed` correctly. If these are variables, you need to add `$` to them.

There are [Umbraco library functions](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary) to compare dates.

Your code should be something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="currenttime" select="umbraco.library:CurrentDate()" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="umbraco.library.DateGreaterThan($dateEvent, $currenttime)">
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">Event is not yet live</a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="umbraco.library.DateGreaterThan($currenttime, $dateEvent) and   umbraco.library.DateGreaterThanOrEqual($dateEventpassed, $currenttime)">
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}/live.aspx">Event is live</a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}/different.aspx">Event has passed</a>
    </xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: DateEvent and dateEventPassed are Date Picker with Time fields i added to this document. I initially had something very similar to your suggestion but it didn't seem to compare time and only seemed to compare date.

For instance: It could be that dateEvent is 08-08-2013 14:00 and dateEventpassend could be 08-08-2013 17:00. Now between 14:00 and 17:00 it should say "Event is Live". But with DateGreaterThanToday this does not seem to work. 

Might this be a problem with my server time settings?

Comment: DateGreaterThanToday only compares date according to this link http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/10408-Time-comparison-with-XSLT. I have amended my answer to use DateGreaterThan instead, which should compare time as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this result:

```
                <xsl:variable name="huidigetijd" select="umbraco.library:CurrentDate()" />  
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="umbraco.library:DateGreaterThan(dateEvent, $huidigetijd)">
                    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">Event is not yet live</a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="umbraco.library:DateGreaterThan($huidigetijd, dateEvent) and umbraco.library:DateGreaterThan(dateEventpassed, $huidigetijd)">
                        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}/live.aspx">Event is live</a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}/different.aspx">Event has passed</a>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
```

Credits go to Ollie P for providing me with a workable answer.